# Sticky Header Jumps Around

Tags: javascript, html, css, header, sticky

Im working on a site now with a sticky header.  The issue im having is that it isnt perfectly sticky.  it jumps around a lot and wont stick back into place.  any ideas on how to fix this?  you can see it here at dupontstudios.com.  heres a snippet of code.  thanks!

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
        // Do our DOM lookups beforehand
        var nav_container = $(".nav-container");
        var nav = $("nav");
        nav_container.waypoint({
        handler: function(direction) {
        nav_container.toggleClass('sticky', direction=='down');

        }
        });

<div id = 'top-container'>
   <video id = 'top-vid' autoplay loop width=100% height = 'auto'  class = 'no-mobile' ><source src = 'DS_Intro.mov' type = 'video/mp4'><source src = 'test.webm' type = 'video/webm'></video>
   <div id = 'top-content'>
       <div id = 'top-text'>
           <div id = 'top-img'>
               <img src='ds_white.png' width = "100%" height = 'auto'>
           </div>
           <h1 id = 'top-slogan'>a boutique video production studio</h1>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class = 'nav-container'>
    <nav>
        <div id = 'nav-items-container'>
            <ul class='nav-items'>
                <li class='nav-item'><a href='#what'>what</a></li>
                <li class='nav-item'><a href='#how'>how</a></li>
                <li class='nav-item'><a href='#why'>why</a></li>
                <li class='nav-item'><a href='#where'>where</a></li>
                <li class='nav-item'><a href='#who'>who</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks okay on my machine

Comment: what browser are you using? maybe its a chrome issue

Comment: Chrome 27 / OS X 10.8.4